# Add TapGestureRecogniser to UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have looked at similar questions and tried the answers and I can't get them working, so apologies if this is a duplicate question.

I have two address fields on my table view that get added dynamically in static cells. When the user enters an address in the first box I want the question of 'Copy address' to appear when they click on the second address field and then copy the address if they answer 'yes'. I have this working on tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath, however it doesn't work when the user directly taps the UITextView in the field. I have tried adding the following to the viewDidLoad() function:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self.billingAddress addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

But the following code doesn't fire when the UITextView billingAddress is tapped.

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"I am here");
}
```

I should note that billingAddress is defined as a UITextField property and assigned the cell's detail in the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath from the static cell. This is done using the following code:

```
if (section == 0 && row == 3) {
    BFCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckoutInputCell"];
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"Billing Address";
    cell.nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Populaire" size:23.0f];
    cell.textField.placeholder = @"Required";
    self.billingAddress = cell.textField;
    cell.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    return cell;
}
```

I'm wondering if I'm assigning the tap gesture to the wrong place and it should be assigned to cell.textField. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what happens is a conflict between the textfield and the gesture recognizer. I'd use the `UITextFieldDelegate` `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` to detect when the user taps on the text field.

Answer (score 0):

it's a big mistake to hold a reference of an object belongs to a `UITableViewCell`.

It is better to add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the text field inside the cell directlly when by having a boolean flad in the cell to tell it if this is the one should respond to touch.

```
if (section == 0 && row == 3) {
    BFCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckoutInputCell"];
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"Billing Address";
    cell.nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Populaire" size:23.0f];
    cell.textField.placeholder = @"Required";
    //self.billingAddress = cell.textField; // wrong way.
    cell.addTouchFlag = true  // do this instead.
    cell.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    return cell;
}
```

and both

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self.textField addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"I am here");
}
```

Should be in the cell class (If you don't have one you sould create it).

**Update:** in [Charles Thierry answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039009/1066762) he has a good point that using the delegate method is better way detect the user tap insid the textField. but you should do it the same way I mentioned above. Which means the cell class will conform `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`